# Disable upward movement animation of label in TextField (Jetpack compose)

Tags: android, textfield, android-jetpack-compose

On tapping a `TextField`, created with Jetpack compose, the label of `TextField` moves upward. How do we disable this?
Or is there any other way the `TexField` would work like an `EditText` in `View` system where we have hint which disappears on tapping the `EditText`?

Comment: Currently (`1.0.0-beta08`) it is not possible to disable it in the `TextField`. If you need an `EditText` just use a `BasicTextField`

Comment: Ok.............

Answer (score 10):

Jetpack compose version - 1.0.3

`placeholder` attribute might be what you are looking for.
But, the text doesn't disappear on clicking the `TextField`.
It disappears only when the user enters some input text.

**Default state**

[image: Default state]

**Focused state**

[image: Focused state]

**After entering input**

[image: After entering input]

**Code**

```
TextField(
    placeholder = { Text(text = "Label") },
    // Other attributes
)
```

Comment: Here is the answer I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

You can use placeholder with `state`.

```
var focusState by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
placeholder = {
    Text(
         text = if (focusState) "" else "label",       
    )
}
```

and `focusState` you take from `onFocusChanged`

```
TextField(
          modifier = Modifier
                .onFocusChanged { focus ->
                    focusState = focus.isFocused
                }
```